# Relacion de cantidades en tablas de SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Buen día a todos

La pregunta es la siguiente,en las tablas, como relacionan las cantidades de un producto por ejemplo, en una tabla es de bodega  y la otra tabla es de exhibición, para insertar en la tabla de exhibición se tienen que ir los productos de la tabla bodega a la tabla exhibición,  como se realiza ese proceso, se hace una función que valide la cantidad en la tabla de bodega posteriormente si cumple con la validación se le resta a la tabla bodega  la cantidad y se le inserta la misma  cantidad a la tabla exhibición? es algo así o ¿cual es la forma de hacerlo?,
otra¿Como saber cual es el mejor query? como se mide el rendimiento de diferentes query que realizan el  mismo trabajo.

Comment: Necesitas explicar mejor o al menos poner las tablas que tienes. Parece que te falta una tabla de movimientos que te pueda ayudar a mantener un control. Me parece extraño que haya una tabla de bodega y otra de exhibición cuando debería de ser una sola tabla de ubicaciones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que tienes un problema de diseño de la base de datos. Todo depende de los requerimientos que tengas. Una solución simple sería tener de por ejemplo una tabla `STOCK` con las columnas `PRODUCTOID, SITUACIONID, CANTIDAD` y otra denominada `SITUACIONES` con los campos `SITUACIONID, SITUACION` con los valores 1 BODEGA y 2 EXPOSICION.
Cuando entra producto nuevo a la bodega se hace un `INSERT` en la tabla `STOCK` con la cantidad que entre con `SITUACIONID=1`. Cuando se aumenta la cantidad de un producto se realiza un `UPDATE` de ese `PRODUCTOID`, aumentando la cantidad existente con la nueva. 
Cuando una cantidad de un producto pasa a exposición, se hacen dos `UPDATE`, uno resta la cantidad de producto con `SITUACIONID=1` y lo aumenta en `SITUACIONID=2`, previamente deberás saber si tienes una entrada en la tabla STOCK con ese producto en `SITUACIONID=2`, en caso contrario, ese segundo `UPDATE` sería un `INSERT`. Para asegurar que los datos son correctos en caso de error o fallo, las dos sentencias se englobarían en una transacción.

Pero lo puedes complicar. Puede que te pidan conocer el histórico de movimientos que han habido. Para ello deberás tener de otra tabla que podemos llamar MOVIMIENTOS_BODEGA, donde se insertan las entradas y salidas al STOCK, positivas si aumenta la cantidad en la bodega, negativas si sale, junto con la fecha del movimiento.

Comment: Gracias por tus comentarios Roger,justamente  resolviste mi duda y me diste una nueva idea , ¿hay alguna documentación que pueda leer sobre diseño de base de datos?,si es así me podrías pasar el link.

Comment: En [este enlace](https://www.uoc.edu/pdf/masters/oficiales/img/913.pdf) tienes un extenso documento (en formato PDF)  con algún capítulo que te puede interesar, al menos los referentes a la introducción y al modelo relacional.